# Getting rid of init messages - systemd

Tags: raspbian, systemd

I have successfully removed the logo and added a splash screen. But I still get text output before and after the splash image.

I am using Raspbian Jessie Lite and I think that this has something to do with systemd. So I tried the instructions from this [page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot).

This is my commandline.txt

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty3 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes quiet loglevel=0 rd.systemd.show_status=false vt.global_cursor_default=0 logo.nologo rootwait
```

I have also removed the plymouth and plymouth-show scripts from /etc/init.d/

No text should be seen now, but I still do get it. Why? How can I get a completely clean boot with only the splash image.

Comment: Sorry I can't solve issue for you but here are my two cents: I had same issue and somehow I resolved it - I don't remember how. It was something with tweeking kernel options and something with fb, but don't take my words for 100% true. It is possible and you should only see log on tty3 with your config while your HDMI output (tty1) should be clean.

Comment: by the way, do you see only systemd log or you also see kernel log on your tty1? because with your cmdline.txt there should be no kernel log on tty1. There is /etc/inittab file where this stuff can be tweeked, but I don't know if systemd uses it or something else

Comment: I think I get both. I get messages like:
Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
Found device /dev/ttyAMA0
Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen
etc
I even took out Plymouth from the init.d scripts and still there are messages. I have no clue what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove plymouth
```

Solved it. Thanks to robinho for the idea.